# How to replace two columns by one with condition? [pandas]

Tags: pandas

I have example pandas data frame like this:

```
n1    n2

10    110
25    30
8     40
```

and I need to have one column counting the absolute value of those two, like this:

```
  n

  10
  5
  32
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

[Basic intro to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

```
# Set up Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a= [10, 25, 8], b = [110, 30, 40]))
df 
    a    b
0  10  110
1  25   30
2   8   40

# Make calculation
df["c"] = (df["a"]-df["b"]).abs()
df
    a    b    c
0  10  110  100
1  25   30    5
2   8   40   32
```

[.abs() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html?highlight=abs#pandas.Series.abs)